# Is it okay to ask questions regarding being a bioinformatician?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if the Bioinformatics SE is a good place to post questions relating to the process of research in bioinformatics.

- Example:

  - What is the proper way to format a PK/PD model for a published report?

**Question**:

> Is it okay to ask questions relating to *being* a bioinformatician, rather than just the subject matter itself?

I am not sure if other Stack Exchange sites would be better suited for this type of subject matter, such as the Academia Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that presenting/visualising data is very significant part of bioinformatcs and it should be questioned (and answered). So the example of yours I find completely fine.

However, I would try to cut questions like "What languages should bioinformatian learn?", "How to apply for a grant in bioinformatics?" or "Where to publish good bioinformatics research?", just because it is not really constructive.

As conclusion, I think it would be very hard to define a border.

Comment: I agree to this point. Visualization is an integral part and community should help each other to get these problems sorted. Getting to know about grants and publication information, should not be the prerogative of the community. Rather these should be something that their employing institutions should take care of.

Comment: I guess "grants and publication information" can be asked on [academia stack exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com).

Comment: "How to apply for a grant in <area>" would likely get shot down on other SE sites as well. It's not a very specific question.